# NUnit cannot call properly method as Program can. How to Mock it properly?

Tags: c#, windows, nunit, moq

In Nunit I try to test a method. I prepared the same input as in production code, but still method which do my work doesn't call properly. Tried to mock it, with no effect at this moment.

I was told that moq is the answer and it won't be easy, but send me a "Similar" question from this forum. below is try of all that I could. all found in that topic was implemented, but service is still not called properly. Checked if in normal case it would work (program.cs) and there function is called, and works as it should.

```
public class Helper
    {
    public string a;
    public string b;
    public Helper(string aa, string bb)
    {
        a = aa;
        b = bb;  //here is some transformation, but I checked it, and it's working properly
    }

}


public class Service
{
    public static string NotWorkingFunction(Helper o)
    {
        InternallService w = ThatPrivateFunctionWorks(o);
        return ThatPrivateFunctionDont(w);
    }

    private InternallService ThatPrivateFunctionWorks(Helper o)
    {
        return DLL_external.SomeInternalService(o);   //call was ok in both program, and in NUnit
    }

    ThatPrivateFunctionDont(InternallService w)
    {
        return DLL_external.CallingServiceFarAwayFromDLL(w); //this one works if is in part of program, but does not from NUnit. checks if have permission from Windows Credentials, then do a work. Error here from NUnit is that he cannot even call this function!

    }

}

public class InternallService
{
    public string smth;
    public InternallService(Helper o)
    {
        smth = o.a;
    }
}
public class DLL_external
{
    public InternallService SomeInternalService(Helper o)
    {
        InternallService p = new InternallService(o);
        return p; //prepare service for function. does not need to connect. output also is checked n another way, and is ok.

    }
    public InternallService CallingServiceFarAwayFromDLL(InternallService o)
    {
        return o; //here it connects to the service (don't know how, which protocol etc. works if run under program.cs)
    }

}
```

in Nunit

```
 public class Test
{
[Test]
public void Tester()
{

    Mock<Helper> MockedObject = new Mock<Helper>("a", "B"); //Mocking an object
    Mock<Service> MockedService = new Mock<Service>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    var Helper = new Helper("a", "B");
    Service.NotWorkingFunction(MockedObject.Object); //still does not work properly. cannot call service inside the function (But very similar thing Can, but in Program.cs)

    MockedService.Object.NotWorkingFunction(MockedObject.Object);//service does not call
    MockedService.Setup(p => p.NotWorkingFunction(MockedObject.Object)); //found at Stack overflow, but still function is not called
                                                                         //of course all uncompiling things are commented in mine code
}
}
```

Expected to work. but still don't know how call it to test from NUnit. Maybe I am wrong with tool, which I use.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I trust your class is not *really* called `Object`? What is your test actually trying to test? Mocks are for dependencies that you *don't* want to test, i.e. they replace the actual objects with fake ones. They are used for dependencies that you don't want to be called.

Comment: The code as is doesn't compile, it's missing private/public markers and as well as static for classes. There is no class `InternalService`. The missing parts can be dummy/empty as long as the code piece compiles in the end.

Comment: @MarkusDeibel Thanks for specfying :-)
but more important things which I want to call is in Internall service, which I cannot access. but I have my kode (something like I written as example. tried to show how it looks, and what depencies are working)

Comment: "I try to test if whole thing is working " - you can't test if whole thing is working if you Mock things out. Mocks deliberately stop you testing parts of the code. Can you say, very simply, what exactly you are trying to test and what happens - "still does not work properly" is not enough

Comment: @iakobski ok, but how I can do this in NUnit? I started to mock, because clear writing code into test, does not work.

Comment: I'm trying to help, I really am, but you've not answered any question I and others have asked.

Comment: hmmm.. I did many changes inside the code to make it readeble (I hope), and try to answer 
@iakobski So another try. 
I try to test in Nunit, class with only 1 public method. this method require to connect to base with my Windows credentials. it's breaking while connecting. Tried to do so like I did in program.cs, and did not work. tried to mock, but also no. the requirement is to do this in NUnit. Maybe another technology can help, I don't know. I still try to do research on this forum and net tutorials, but haven't found anything working actually.

Comment: I want to force NUnit, to run my code properly, by which I mean by analazing proper entry, log on to service, and download the right file. Still cannot call external service, even check if file exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of unit testing is that you test individual units of code rather than the whole system. Integration testing is where you test the whole system. You should test each public interface of each class individually. If that class has dependencies that you want to exclude from the test, you can create mocks of those dependencies: these are fake objects that are called *instead* of calling your actual code.

For example, to test the function that you say is not working you write a test that calls that function, not a test that goes through the rest of the code to hopefully call that function. You need to set up the data the function being tested needs, either directly or with mock objects. So tests for Dll_External might start like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class Dll_External_Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void ShouldReturnAnInternalServiceFromCallingServiceFarAwayFromDLL()
    {
        // setup
       Helper helper = new Helper("a", "B");
       InternallService internalService = new InternallService(helper);
       DLL_external dLL_external = new DLL_external();

       // act
       var result = dLL_external.CallingServiceFarAwayFromDLL(internalService);

       // assert
       Assert.IsNotNull(result);
       Assert.IsTrue(result is InternallService);
       // add more assertions for what you expect the result to be
    }
}
```

You will see this test does not use `Service` at all - it is only testing DLL_External and only creates the objects it needs to be able to do that.

Incidentally, the code you have shown won't compile: you need an object to call a method on. You can only call static methods directly on the class like `ClassName.StaticMethod()`. Also, it can be a bit confusing if your objects have the same name as the class, convention is that class names start with a capital letter and instances (objects) start with a lower case letter.

Comment: DLL externall cannot be called from NUnit.

Comment: Why not? You've shown it as `public`. Do you need to add a reference or using statement to your test project?